# I have a grid where I input data and depending on the values in the columns need to create hyperlinks that redirect to another grid In maui Syncfusion

Tags: maui, syncfusion

"I have a grid where I input data, and depending on the values in the columns, I need to create hyperlinks that redirect to another grid." In Maui Syncfusion

In Maui SyncfusionIi need to  values in the columns, I need to create hyperlinks that redirect to another grid.

Comment: please read [ask] before posting

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

DataGrid provides template column support. It is used to load any view inside a cell. You can load a customized label to show the hyperlink-like text. Please refer to the below link for more information,

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/maui/user-interface/controls/label#create-a-hyperlink

I have created a basic example of using hyperlinks to go between two datagrids. The customized label's TapGestureRecognizer is used to detect taps, and you can then utilize taps to navigate between the pages.

Code snippet:

```
<syncfusion:DataGridTemplateColumn MappingName="PageLink">
    <syncfusion:DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <local:HyperlinkLabel Text="Go To" VerticalTextAlignment="Center"
                                Url="{Binding PageLink}"
                                HorizontalOptions="Center"/>
        </DataTemplate>
    </syncfusion:DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
</syncfusion:DataGridTemplateColumn>
```

Sample Image
[image: DataGrid_HyperLinkNavigation]